# Best practice for groupby on Parquet file

Tags: python, pyspark, parquet, dask

We have a 1.5BM records spread out in several csv files. We need to groupby on several columns in order to generate a `count` aggregate.
Our current strategy is to:

1. Load them into a dataframe (using `Dask` or `pyspark`)
2. Aggregate columns in order to generate 2 columns as key:value (we are not sure if this is worthwhile)
3. Save file as `Parquet`
4. Read the `Parquet` file (`Dask` or `pyspark`) and run a groupby on the index of the dataframe.

What is the best practice for an efficient groupby on a `Parquet` file?
How beneficial is it to perform the groupby on the index rather then on a column (or a group of columns)?
We understand that there is a `partition` that can assist - but in our case we need to groupby on the entire dataset - so we don't think it is relevant.

Comment: Is there any reason that you don't groupby on the dataframe made from CSVs directly? Are you expecting to do different groupbies? What data type are your grouping columns?

Comment: We have 1.5 Billion records (and growing) - thus trying to find the most efficient way to run the groupby. The groupby column is currently `text` .  we would also like to save two additional columns into a list (within the column)

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing a groupby-aggregation with a known aggregation like `count` or `mean` then your partitioning won't make that much of a difference.  This should be relatively fast regardless.

If you are doing a groupby-apply with a non-trivial apply function (like running an sklearn model on each group) then you will have a much faster experience if you store your data so that the grouping column is sorted in parquet.

#### Edit:

That being said, even though groupby-count doesn't especially encourage smart partitioning it's still nice to switch to Parquet.  You'll find that you can read the relevant columns much more quickly.

As a quick disclaimer, dask.dataframe doesn't currently use the count statistics within parquet to accelerate queries, except by filtering within the `read_parquet` function and to help identify sorted columns.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  
Since we are doing a `count` operation then there  is no need setup a partitioning. But is there still value to `read_csv` and then write to `parquet` before performing the groupby operation?  
If we want to save the key value(=count) pairs for future update what would be a possible/optimal key-value store format?